# Secret button on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

I am looking for a way to implement a 'secret' button in a page.
Of course, I could just use CSS to hide the element like this:

*HTML*

```
<div class="secretButton" onclick="secretFunction()"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
.secretButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

*JS*

```
function secretFunction() {
    alert("Secret Alert");
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb2nf/)

But this could too easily be seen in a web inspector.
**What would be the best way to create a such 'secret' element, where security does not matter?**

Perhaps loading an encrypted script containing the 'secret' function `onclick()`?

*Note 1: jQuery can be used.*

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Who should click this button? No matter how you do this, the Web Inspectos will always be able to see it.

Comment: You could see it as some sort of `easter egg`. Anyone could click the button, but it should not be hidden in plain sight.

Comment: You can't use something on the client and also have it not exist at the same time. It either exists and you hide it from the UI or it doesn't exist (full stop)

Comment: Attach a click event handler to an ordinary unsuspecting element via obfuscated Javascript. That's probably about as hidden as you can make it.

Comment: Take some fake google ads or something, stick it on your page and use that as a button. As Laurent said, hidden in plain sight.

Comment: You can't hide elements from the web inspector. Some of the best hidden easter eggs I've seen are the ones that you have to type and the js os obfuscated (like the 1337 on youtube or the arrow code)

Comment: A [server side image map](http://jimthatcher.com/webcourse5.htm) may do what you need, that gives the user an indication which image is mapped, but not which positions in the image to click for something to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Although this is kinda opinion based, I like the question about what's a good approach to place an easter egg into a website. Don't be too serious about it :-)*

Generate the button completely with JS like:

```
document.easterEggBtn = function() {
    button = $('<div/>');
    button.addClass('secretButton');
    button.on('click', 'easterEggFunction');
    // Add more attributes
    $('#buttonOuter').append(button);
}
```

Then use an [online javascript obfuscator](https://www.google.com/?q=javascript+online+obfuscator#q=javascript+online+obfuscator), and put that obfuscated code into your website.

Won't  hide from any DOM inspector of course, but if someone only looks into the sourecode, he won't spot it right away.

Another way is to *fake 'secret buttons'*: Put many hidden buttons into the code, so the visitor gets confused and doesn't know which of the 50 buttons is the real *easter egg*.